# Python 2.7 psutil реальная память процесса

Tags: python, windows, память, процесс

Доброго времени суток всем, подскажите каким образом вытащить из psutil информацию о памяти процесса, чтобы она соответствовала диспетчеру задач? для примера пользуюсь такой штукой:

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.pids():
    try:
        p = psutil.Process(proc)
        m = p.memory_info_ex()
        print (p.name(), m)
    except:
        pass
```

Которая в итоге выводи имя процесса и всю его информацию, но я там не нашел представления нужного. Может нужно еще арифметику какую?

Там все числа в байтах выдаются, согласно документации, из диспетчера в байты переводил и сравнивал. В килобайты все сводить пробовал - тоже не сошлось.

Comment: а как сильно расходится, и какие цифры вы сравниваете? psutil.memory_info выдает 7 параметров - vms, rss, shared, text, lib, data, dirty. вам нужен rss насколько я понимаю

Comment: Нужен по идее rss, да, а расходятся примерно так: в диспетчере задач   2404КБ, а в параметре rss - 6950912L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Windows есть монитор ресурсов (вызываемый из диспетчера задач), так вот параметр rss отображает информацию именно из колонки "Рабочий набор", а сам диспетчер задач отображает не полную память, а только частную.

Comment: Что такое "Рабочий набор" ясно (недавно использованные страницы процесса) это близко к понятию RSS (страницы процесса, которые в физической памяти прямо сейчас находятся) А что вы понимаете под "реальной памятью", "полной памятью", "частной памятью"? Например, если процесс использует dll, то входит ли потребляемая ею память в "реальную память". Если второй процесс запустится, который использует эту же уже уже загруженную dll, то дважды память под dll вы хотите считать или только один раз в "реальной памяти"? Как изменятся эти значения, если до загрузки второго процесса, dll в своп лежала?

Comment: Под реальной памятью я понимаю ту память, которая отображается в диспетчере задач, под полной памятью - вместе с кешем и библиотеками, а под частной - исключительно сам процесс без библиотек и прочего)

Comment: то есть "реальная память" == "рабочий набор" в ваших терминах? Что вы под "кэшем" понимаете (файловых кэш? -- тогда причём здесь память процесса?). "Рабочий набор" может включать в себя загруженные в память библиотеки (например, если недавно использовались). Диспетчер задач может показывать несколько колонок. Колонка "память" в диспетчере задач показывает "частный рабочий набор" (что очевидно отличается от просто "рабочий набор" колонки в диспетчере задач). Вот [вопрос, где показывается какие метрики памяти доступны в Windows и что они означают](http://superuser.com/q/359295/13868)